# Audio device error encountered. - Error Code: 0x4

Tags: c#, vba, exception

I'm working on a speech recognition program on C# (using Visual Basic 2013), and when I compile and try it out, it works fine for the first command but gives me a weird exception when I speak the second command.
Details:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.AudioException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.AudioException' occurred in System.Speech.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Audio device error encountered. - Error Code: 0x4

My code is quite a few lines long, but here's the first and possibly related part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web;

namespace JarvisTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer JARVIS = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    string QEvent;
    string ProcWindow;
    double timer = 10;
    int count = 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    string Temperature;
    string Condition;
    string Humidity;
    string WindSpeed;
    string Town;
    string TFCond;
    string TFHigh;
    string TFLow;
    string Stuff;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Aristotelis\Documents\JarvisTest.txt")))));
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }


    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);

        string speech = e.Result.Text;
        switch (speech)
        {
            //WOLFRAM
            case "ram":               
                WolframAlpha();
                JARVIS.Speak("time for stuff" + Stuff);
                break;

            //WEATHER

            case "hows the weather":
                GetWeather();
                JARVIS.Speak("The temperature in " + Town + " is " + Temperature + " degrees.");
                break;

            //GREETINGS
            case "hello":
            case "hello jarvis":
                if (ranNum < 6) { JARVIS.Speak("Hello sir"); }
                else if (ranNum > 5) { JARVIS.Speak("Hi"); }
                break;
```

I'm not sure what causes the problem. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Stack tracing shows:

```
Expression: ((System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.AudioException)$exception).StackTrace
Value:
at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.Speak(Prompt prompt)
at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(String textToSpeak)
at JarvisTest.Form1._recognizer_SpeechRecognized(Object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Aristotelis\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\JarvisTest\JarvisTest\Form1.cs:line 77
at System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognizedProxy(Object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: What does Google say?

Comment: I did search Google of course when I encountered the error, but I found no relative information- only found some other errors such as 0x2, etc. That's why I wanted some help from here.

Comment: Can you get an HRESULT of your exception? Start VS in debug-mode and when the exception occurs, try to get an HRESULT.

Comment: You should look for that on Google for example

Comment: Nothing useful comes from Google, e.g. problems regarding databases. I cannot link it at all with a System.Speech issue.

Comment: What about stacktrace? Can you trace it to a particular line-number in your code?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs right before the program is about to talk, after I give the second command. For example:
I say Hello, the program says Hi/Hi Sir.
If I say Hello again, the program will give me the exception.
So the troubling line is the one with the corresponding JARVIS.Speak("...") in it.

Comment: I mean a real stacktrace... The one displayed when the exception occured... can you debug it and break before it speaks? - So it appears the SpeechSynthesizer is not working properly

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll update the post in a sec with Stacktrace.

Comment: Try to debug your application and make sure you have properly initialized speechsynthesis. Please mark line 77, too

Comment: Line 77 is just the line with the corresponding JARVIS.Speak("...").
I've already looked at the code and there's nothing really that should be causing problems, but I'll look into it more. Any other suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally occurs when your speech device is damaged.
Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9075023b-8bc4-4632-a573-77470b403a48/i-get-an-audioexception-0x2 ???

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ajay. I did come across that article as well, and I did try to see whether there's a problem with my audio device (or any of my devices) but there's none. I also read somewhere that perhaps connecting my speakers with the notebook will solve the issue, but it didn't.

I'm convinced that the problem is hardware related, but I have no idea what to look for, what to check and what to do... I'm really stumped at this mo.